# Suspected Malware: Computer turning off all forms of virus protection automatically

Tags: windows-8, virus, anti-virus, malware, virus-removal

I'm running windows 8.1 and very recently I got error messages saying that I had no virus protection on. I had windows firewall, avg free and spybot search and destroy running. All were turned off and I cannot turn them back on. I scanned my computer with Malwarebytes but yielded no results. Does anyone suspect a particular malware or know what I should try next?

Comment: Have you tried booting in safe mode, running a scan and checking the status of your security here?

Comment: No, why would that be different though?

Comment: If you do indeed have a virus which has not managed to embed itself into files required to boot then safe mode will allow you to boot and scan your computer without an active virus running. It might not work depending on the situation, but it's an option before doing anything drastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitman pro has a kickstarter kit you can install to a USB stick (will clear the content of the USB stick upon installation, so backup or use empty) which will boot into a save windows environment to elimiate any virusses or spyware. Because hitman is the first thing that loads, virussus can't shut it down. An active internet connection is required, but that should not be any problem.

Comment: Interesting, hitman wouldn't affect personal data though would it?

Comment: No. Its just a spyware scanner that uses a special method to boot windows and ensures that only hitman is run, not anything else, so it can safely scan the system. The only thing is that it needs to be made to a bootalbe usb stick which requires a special bootloader which requires it being empty.